# How to Bind SubTotal in ItemsControl Group

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Picture this DTO-like class:

```
class LineItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Description { get; set; }

    private decimal m_Amount;
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return m_Amount; }
        set
        {
            if (m_Amount == value)
                return;
            m_Amount = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Amount"));
        }
    }
}
```

And a binding like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Amount}"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This would look something like:

[image]

Now, I want a total at the bottom. Moreover, I want it to update when Amount changes.

Something like this:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Text="{Binding LineItems, 
            Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

For this:

[image]

But what is MyConverter? And, is it even a correct approach?

My question:

This does not work since the converter is called only the first time it is bound. I want it to reflect user changes, and I need to handle unknown quantity of LineItems. Certainly I am not the first to hit this. **Is there a way?**

Comment: Found surprisingly little on the subject, have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810188/calculate-sum-average-based-on-list-of-items-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are like this:

[image]

This is the CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // used to force databinding to refresh
    public int FakeProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(FakePropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FakePropertyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FakePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FakeProperty", 
        typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FakeProperty++;
    }

}

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Family { get; set; }
    private int m_Value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
        set
        {
            if (m_Value == value)
                return;
            m_Value = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }
}

public class Items : ObservableCollection<Item>
{
    public Items()
    {
        this.Add(new Item { Family = "One", Value = 1 });
        this.Add(new Item { Family = "One", Value = 2 });
        this.Add(new Item { Family = "Two", Value = 3 });
        this.Add(new Item { Family = "Two", Value = 4 });
        this.Add(new Item { Family = "Two", Value = 5 });
        this.Add(new Item { Family = "Three", Value = 6 });
        this.Add(new Item { Family = "Three", Value = 7 });
    }
}

public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                    object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var _Default = 0;
        if (values == null || values.Length != 2)
            return _Default;
        var _Collection = values[0] as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
        if (_Collection == null)
            return _Default;
        var _Items = _Collection.Cast<Item>();
        if (_Items == null)
            return _Default;
        var _Sum = _Items.Sum(x => x.Value);
        return _Sum;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, obje
                    ct parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And this XAML:

```
xmlns:sort="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Name="This"

<Window.Resources>
    <local:Items x:Key="MyData" />
    <local:SumConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyView" Source="{StaticResource MyData}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Family" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <sort:SortDescription PropertyName="Value" Direction="Ascending" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyView}}"
        Name="MyItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <!-- group header -->
                                <Border Padding="10,5,0,5" Margin="0,10,0,10" 
                                        Background="Gainsboro" CornerRadius="10">
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                                            Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </Border>
                                <!-- group items -->
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                <!-- group footer -->
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" 
                                            BorderThickness="0,.5,0,0"
                                            Margin="0,5,0,10">
                                    <TextBlock Width="100" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                            TextAlignment="Right" 
                                            Padding="0,0,5,0">
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding 
                                             StringFormat="{}{0:C}"
                                             Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="Items" />
                                                <Binding Path="FakeProperty" 
                                                        ElementName="This"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{x:Null}" />
        </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="ItemsPresenter">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:C}, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" 
                        TextAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                        Width="100" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, 
                        StringFormat={}Value is {0}}" 
                        FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DimGray" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <!-- list footer -->
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,.5,0,0" Margin="0,5,0,10">
        <TextBlock Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextAlignment="Right" 
                   Padding="0,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}" 
                              StringFormat="{}{0:C}">
                    <Binding Path="ItemsSource" ElementName="MyItemsControl" />
                    <Binding Path="FakeProperty" ElementName="This"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

</StackPanel>
```

What a nightmare to figure out!

Comment: Help me get Microsoft to address this natively, please up-vote my Connect Suggestion: https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/685453/bind-to-one-path-update-based-on-another

Answer (score 2):

You could instead be binding to a property that specifically represents the `AverageAmount` (on your "view model") and ensure that on `PropertyChanged` for each `LineItem` that you send a change notification for the `AverageAmount` property to allow the model to calculate the value and UI to re-get the new value. [Maleak's example shows exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154758/how-to-bind-a-total-value-in-wpf/7154882#7154882).

However, with careful consideration of the overhead of doing so, I would look at something like [BindableLinq](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/) or [Obtics](http://obtics.codeplex.com/) (or [Continuous Linq](http://www.codeplex.com/clinq)) which should handle all of the dependency analysis and change notifications. We've used BindableLinq with great success though at this time, it's not actively being maintained by the guy that started it.

**Edit:**

To give an example of the back-end without using those libraries I mentioned above (which removes the plumbing for handling collection and property changed events):

```
public class ItemListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    public ItemListViewModel()
    {
        _items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsChanged;
    }

    public ICollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get { return _items; } }

    private void OnItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                e.NewItems.Cast<ItemViewModel>().ToList().ForEach(iv => iv.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                e.OldItems.Cast<ItemViewModel>().ToList().ForEach(iv => iv.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Value")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AverageValue"));
        }
    }

    public double AverageValue
    {
        get { return Items.Average(iv => iv.Value); }
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Family { get; set; }
    private int m_Value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
        set
        {
            if (m_Value == value)
                return;

            m_Value = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then your ItemsControl in the XAML binds straight onto the Items property of the view model and the average value binds to the AverageValue property. It'll now handle the notifications required.

To add grouping at another level you'll have to introduce another class "ItemGroupViewModel" that will watch over the parent's Items collection for changes. I would add property change listeners to all items, then if they change their Family property, then add/remove from the local Items collection. If they change their Value property, then fire a PropertyChanged for the AverageValue property.

NOTE: BindableLinq has support for the grouping operation too.